# clone case custom button broken by "

Tags: formula, case, clone

"For example I have a case named "Test123, 321test" when I clone the case "321test" is considered a new field and breaks the formula.

Here is the formula:

```text
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Case/new?defaultFieldValues=ParentId='+(Case.Id)
+',OwnerId='+(Case.OwnerId)
+',Status='+TEXT((Case.Status))
+',Origin='+TEXT((Case.Origin))
+',Priority='+TEXT((Case.Priority))
+',Trending_Topics_Pick_List__c='+TEXT((Case.Trending_Topics_Pick_List__c))
+',OrderID__c='+(Case.OrderID__c)
+',Subject='+(Case.Subject)
+',Description='+(Case.Description)
+',SuppliedEmail='+(Case.SuppliedEmail)
+',SuppliedName='+(Case.SuppliedName)
+',SuppliedCompany='+(Case.SuppliedCompany)
+',SuppliedPhone='+(Case.SuppliedPhone)
+',Language__c='+TEXT((Case.Language__c))
+',Country_of_Origin__c='+TEXT((Case.Country_of_Origin__c))
+',Driver_Category__c='+TEXT((Case.Driver_Category__c))+ IF(ISBLANK(Case.AccountId),NULL,',AccountId='+(Case.AccountId)) )}
```

Anyone has a clue how I can fix this?

Comment: clone case custom button broken by "," (comma).

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL-encode the entire parameter:

```
'/lightning/o/Case/new?defaultFieldValues='+
URLENCODE(ParentId'+(Case.Id)
+',OwnerId='+(Case.OwnerId)
+',Status='+TEXT((Case.Status))
+',Origin='+TEXT((Case.Origin))
+',Priority='+TEXT((Case.Priority))
+',Trending_Topics_Pick_List__c='+TEXT((Case.Trending_Topics_Pick_List__c))
+',OrderID__c='+(Case.OrderID__c)
+',Subject='+(Case.Subject)
+',Description='+(Case.Description)
+',SuppliedEmail='+(Case.SuppliedEmail)
+',SuppliedName='+(Case.SuppliedName)
+',SuppliedCompany='+(Case.SuppliedCompany)
+',SuppliedPhone='+(Case.SuppliedPhone)
+',Language__c='+TEXT((Case.Language__c))
+',Country_of_Origin__c='+TEXT((Case.Country_of_Origin__c))
+',Driver_Category__c='+TEXT((Case.Driver_Category__c))+ IF(ISBLANK(Case.AccountId),NULL,',AccountId='+(Case.AccountId)))
}
```

Edit: Also note that `URLFOR` isn't necessary here, since you're not actually using any of the usual properties you'd use `URLFOR` for. For example, we typically use this function to specify an URL from a global variable with parameters, etc.

For example, an actual use of URLFOR might look like this:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.Case.New,null,[Status='Open'])}
```

Since you're not using any of those features, this is unnecessary.